# How allowing browser (mozilla Firefox) to open paths and open in that browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I made in html file link (a href) file://///IP/subfolder (local network) and install add on Locallinks 0.5.1-signed. In Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m, It can be opened. But in Firefox 39.0, It can't be opened. I installed add-on Local Filesystem Links 0.99.37 in Firefox, It can't be opened too. Please, help me.

Comment: Why do you need add-ons at all? Both browsers are able to open links on localhost.

Comment: I think this is best suited in Add-on support section.

Comment: feeela: No. I am sure you missunderstanding. Open link file location other device. Example server A contains LAMPP. There is a file html in server A want to open NAS/server file sharing. It can't be opened on Firefox (even with add-on). Please help...